# "Cannot resolve symbol "R" - all XML android:ids are correct

Tags: java, android, xml, r.java-file

I edited a small amount of my xml code
(tried to add an `android:src"@drawable/"` but it didn't seem to like it so I deleted it after) 
and my java code (added  `Troop1P1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` to the end of an `OnClickListener`,
and again deleted afterwards [I had already used `findViewByID` for `Troop1P1`]).

However, my whole code has now stopped working, with every "R" in (R.id.) being highlighted, with the text `"Cannot resolve symbol "R""` when hovered over.

In addition, when I run the code I get the following error:

`error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/btnTroop1P2')`.

However, I've checked and I'm fairly sure I've correctly id'd `btnTroop1P2` using `android:id="@+id/btnTroop1P2"`, so I can't find any problems there.

I'd really appreciate any help, I just want to be able to run my project again!

Comment: Please post your code sample here as well!

Comment: Make sure the system's R isn't being imported anywhere. And make sure that btnTroop1P2 isn't referring to itself in the relative layout. A unique view can not be above itself, when there is only one such view.

Comment: `android:id="@+id/btnTroop1P2"` must be **already declared** for a View, before you can reference it in another View.

Answer (score 0):

are you using Eclipse? .if yes go to Project -> Clean... -> Tick your project name -> OK.
Give that a try. I always get similar problems and this solves it for me anyway.

Comment: I'm using android studio, but I've already tried this, using build--> clean project but to no avail. Thanks for the effort though

Comment: Try File>Invalidate Caches/Restart. Also check if any of your XMLs contains any errors (like missing brackets, names etc.)

Answer (score 0):

When this occurs, it's usually because you have an error in your layout XML. When an error exists there, the R file is not generated. Therefore, `Cannot resolve symbol "R"` is the only information Java can give you. Go back into your drawable, layout, or any other XML you've been playing with and make sure you have everything properly formatted.

Comment: I've checked and triple checked it but I can't find any issues. I guess I'll check again tomorrrow and see if I can find any errors

Comment: Did this help at all?